# RedBeanPHP передать ORDER BY в качестве параметра

Tags: mysql, redbeanphp

Здравствуйте

есть вот такой запрос:

```
$content = R::findAll('team', 'ORDER BY ? ', [$sort]);
```

если распечатать запрос получим вот такой результат:

```
SELECT `team`.* FROM `team` ORDER BY 'date DESC' -- keep-cache
resultset: 8 rows
```

Как видим сортировка записей идет по `date DESC` но сортировка НЕ происходит

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем дело!?

Comment: Текст запроса синтаксически неверен - параметр класса ORDER BY не должен быть взят в кавычки. В нынешнем виде выполняется сортировка по литералу - т.е. никак, что и наблюдается.

Comment: а как же в таком случае поступить?

Comment: А я почём знаю? я про эти redbeans второй раз в жизни слышу, и оба раза тут. Читай мануал, там должно быть... или примеры смотри... хотя я думаю, что надо просто составлять ORDER BY литерально, а не подставлять как параметр. Ну типа `$content = R::findAll('team', "ORDER BY $sort");` (и молиться, что обойдётся без инъекции).

Comment: может есть Вариант удалить кавычки у переменной sort?

Comment: посмотрите вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072264/redbeanphp-values-in-find-dont-work

Comment: и вот эти https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907687/why-doesnt-binding-parameter-in-order-by-clause-order-the-results  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542410/how-do-i-set-order-by-params-using-prepared-pdo-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто попробуйте следующий вариант, сначала формируем строку $params

```
$params = ' ORDER BY ' . $column . ' ' . $sort;
$content = R::findAll('team', params );
```

// Мне вот этот код помог
$user_stories = R::findLike( 'story', ['us_id' => [ $id ]], ' ORDER BY id DESC ' );
Story - название таблицы,
Us_id - Столбец, по которому ищу,
Id - тот id, который идентифицирует
ORDER BY id DESC - Выкладывает содержимое по id в обратном порядке.

Потом через цикл foreach можно все вывести.
Надеюсь, я тебе помог) Ответ нашел в документации у Redbeanphp)
https://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/finding

Comment: Вы ограничиваете сортировку одним полем. Нужна сортировка по неизвестному полю.

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis Просто сформируйте необходимое вам в строке...

`$params = '..'; 
$content = R::findAll('team', $params);`

Answer (score 0):

Направление сортировки нужно указывать в директиве сортировки, а не вместе с именем столбца:

```
$content = R::findAll('team', 'ORDER BY ? DESC', [$sort]);
```

Но так тоже не заработает так как вам нужно указывать колонку как колонку, а не как строку. Иначе говоря остаётся только вставлять название колонки явно:

```
$content = R::findAll('team', "ORDER BY `$sort` DESC");
```

В этом случае необходимо будет фильтровать содержимое переменной `$sort`, лучше всего по белому списку доступных для сортировки полей.

Answer (score 0):

Параметры сортировки нельзя параметризовать плейсхолдерами, потому что это не данные, а отсылка к колонкам запроса.

Если ваш(redbean) sqlbuilder не позволяет построить этот clause, придётся формировать эту часть запроса вручную.

```
$orderBy = sprintf('ORDER BY %s', $sort);
$content = R::findAll('team', $orderBy);
```

*Не забудьте убедиться, что `$sort` содержит то, что вы ожидаете (желательно строить его из белого списка допустимых колонок сортировки)*

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже столкнулся с сортировкой, вот так будет работать

```
    $content = R::findAll('team', 'ORDER BY id ASC');
```

id и ASC свои подставите.